# Imported .SVG icon, in QGIS, can not be shown on LIZMAP

Tags: qgis, svg, lizmap

I imported an icon(.SVG) in QGIS and then transffered whole project on QGIS server using FileZilla.

However i cannot see newly imported simbology on LIZMAP web client although it is active  in QGIS.

I also tried having .SVG file in MEDIA folder, for transfer.

Is there a way to get this on visible on Lizmap web client?

regards

Comment: Can you explain what you have done with the media folder ? It's working well with media folder.

Answer (score 2):

You have two solutions to use your own SVG in a QGS project that is shared on Lizmap or shared with other people :

### Best solution : embedded SVG : Easy fast reliable

You can embed the SVG file in your project. In the layer styling, you have to choose the SVG image you want. Then below the SVG images click on the down arrow then click on `embed file`. An explorer window will pop up to confirm the SVG file you want, and then it will be embedded in your project. Use Lizmap plugin and save then update the files with your FTP client.

[image]

### Second solution : Share the same file structure local and remote

You can also add your svg file in a folder named MEDIA locally. Then in QGIS set the SVG source file to be taken in this folder. Then upload MEDIA folder and your project files.

Cons : you always have to share a MEDIA folder with your project, if naming is changed the link is broken, more files.

Answer (score 2):

Following the second solution of Corentin Lemaitre, you can use a single "media" folder for your whole Lizmap instance. So the SVG is available everywhere in all QGIS projects (whatever the folder).

SVG file : `/home/etienne/dev/lizmap/lizmap-docker-master/tests/qgis-projects/media/custom_svg/croissant.svg`

[image]

But if you open the QGS file with a text editor and you loof for the string `croissant`, you will notice QGIS will save a relative path starting with `../`

`<prop v="../media/custom_svg/croissant.svg" k="name"/>`

So as long as the path is valid on the server, it's working.

Link to the [documentation](https://docs.lizmap.com/current/en/publish/configuration/media.html?highlight=icon#use-a-single-media-folder-for-many-lizmap-folders) about the single media folder.

Link to the [documentation](https://docs.lizmap.com/current/en/publish/configuration/media.html#use-for-svg) about the SVG in the media. I just added just now ... :)

Answer (score 0):

I have used media folder and then custom-svg folder in which I placed `.svg` file. From there I have chosen `-Embed-`.
So it seems like combination of 2 proposed solutions worked out although I my self tried this yesterday but for some reason it did not work. Maybe because of not putting file to `/media/custom-svg`. I have just putted `.SVG` into `/media`.

Comment: But choosing `Embed`, then you are not using the `svg` file anymore, because the file is embed in the QGS file itself (encoded as base64). So I don't think it was the issue about the `media` folder. If you want to update the SVG file later, because the file is *embed*, you would need to do it in all projects.